# Is containment of images of linear maps Zariski closed?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra

Consider the set
$$\\\{ (A,B) \in \mathbb{P}^{n\times n-1} \times \mathbb{P}^{n\times n -1} : \text{im}(A) \subseteq \text{im}(B)\}.$$
That is, this is the set of pairs of square matrices $(A,B)$ so that the image of $A$ is contained in the image of $B$. Is this Zariski closed? I would be happy if this were at least true over an algebraically closed field.

I tried to write down explicit equations for this, but my first attempt would involved using determinants of submatrices of $A$, and would fail if $A$ was singular. I had thought that this would follow from the projection theorem for for projective varieties, but am unsure.

Comment: That is not Zariski closed.  Let $A$ be the identity $n\times n$ matrix and let $B$ be a diagonal matrix in which all diagonal entries except one equal $1$, and the last entry is a varying element $t$ in the affine line.  For all $t\neq 0$, the corresponding pair is in your set, but for $t=0$ the pair is not in your set.

Comment: Ah, that is a good point. Thanks! If you add this as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am making my comment an answer.  The specified set is not Zariski closed.  If it were, then its intersection with every Zariski closed subset $C$ would be relatively closed in $C$.  But now let $C$ be the curve, a copy of the affine line, where the first component $A$ is held fixed as the identity $n\times n$ matrix, and the second component is a varying diagonal matrix whose first $n-1$ diagonal entries all equal $1$, yet whose last entry $t$ varies in a copy of the affine line.  The intersection of $C$ with the specified set is a non-closed, dense Zariski open in $C$, namely the open subset where $t$ is invertible.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to see your set is not closed: it is evidently not the whole space of pairs, but yet it contains the open dense set $U\times U$ where $U \subset \mathbb{P}^{n^2-1}$ consists of (classes of) invertible matrices. So your set is different from its closure.